# Как сделать в MySQL запрос SELECT в DelphiXE8 FireDAC

Tags: mysql, delphi, select

Пытаюсь так сделать запрос

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = "3"');
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут таки и написано `"Надо метод Open  использовать для выборки (select)".`
Для операций `insert, update, delete` и прочих как правило `ExecSQL`.
А для `Select` обычно `Open`
Я к тому, что так практически в любых компонентах работы с BD для Delphi.